# How to add a toolbar with a button through e4xmi

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-pde

I have a task to redesign the toolbar of an eclipse-based application. The previous implementation is based on the `e3 plugin.xml` extension points.

I saw that the application uses an `.e4xmi` file to add extensions to the `eclipse Menu`, therefore I'd like to migrate all the toolbars and added buttons to be extended from the `e4xmi` file.

How can I create a toolbar and add a button to it from the `e4xmi` file?
I can't find a documentation for `migrate a button from e3 to e4`...

Comment: This isn't straightforward. If the button uses an old Action it would need to be completely rewritten, if it uses a command handler there still needs to be substantial changes to the handler. I would not recommend doing this.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks greg! So you would recommend to stick with the old `e3` implementations? What if there is a request for a new toolbar with a button? Would you recommend to implement it using a `plugin.xml` or implement it in the `e4xmi` file?

Comment: Personally I would stick to e3 even for new things. Hybrid e3/e4 is tricky. Note that you can only define toolbars for Windows and Parts (views/editors) in the e4xmi. Toolbars inside views and editors are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

E4 uses more generic TrimBar "representing the trim along a Window's edge" to express ToolBar, StatusBar and so on.
Please have a look here to learn more https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#toolbars-toolcontrols-and-drop-down-tool-items

I would give E4 a chance, especially for new things.